# While Datta Guru name abusive words in rhythm of word Dutta appears in mind. How should I overcome that?

Tags: prayer, vedic-chanting, dattatreya

I recently started chanting Jai Guru Datta however during chanting words in rhythm of Dutta and which are abusive starts appearing in brain, hence I stopped chanting. What will be effect of such unwanted mistake and how to overcome that?

Comment: It is only a suggestion.. I think you should continue doing it whatever comes to your mind.. very soon, you will get rid of these negative thoughts.. All the best...